# Is it possible to set this ViewPager without libraries?

Tags: android

I want to achieve this layout style in ViewPager:

[image]

I understand it's easy to implement using ViewPagerIndicator(http://viewpagerindicator.com/), but I want to avoid using external libraries in my project

I've read documentation: http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/tabs.html but I can't find out how to set the style of the Tabs to the one that I'm showing you in screenshot. However, this is implemented in Android Settings - Applications, so I guess it's somehow easy to implement with SDK code.

Any tips?

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK ViewPager is not possible without the additional library. It is only contained in the library and not core code.

Comment: If you go to Settings - Applications in a Tablet, you will see it implemented. I've checked Hireararchy and its a android.support.v4.view.ViewPager. So I guess it should be possible.

Comment: No not without the library which is the android.support.v4 part.

Comment: By "not using library" I mean I do not want to use this library: http://viewpagerindicator.com/ I can use google one.

Comment: Oh, no you don't need that. Google has provided all the stuff you need. Just look at the viewPager samples on the developer site, it shows how it can be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from MuhammadA, I figured out how to do it:

Browse sourcecode from this example in Google Documentation: http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/EffectiveNavigation.zip

Check code from Activity: `CollectionDemoActivity`

Seems easy to implement!